# Ubuntu 12.04 installation stuck on 'where do you live' using CD

Tags: system-installation

I am trying to install my first linux software, Ubuntu 12.04. 
I got an iso image of Ubuntu 12.04 from a PC magazine DVD. I first burned it using ImgBurn on a clean new CD-RW. Then I deleted a 40 GB partition to make it free. I booted from the CD, Ubuntu came up, I selected the install option, followed by the install along windows 7 option.

The installer did not ask me to slide partitions. It said copying files and then showed me a screen where I can select my area of residence. I selected this area and pressed the continue button. after which the mouse icon keeps on spinning busy. It keeps spinning even after the copying files is completed and the same world map is displayed. I can move, do all other things on the ubuntu, like going to settings menu and so on, but this installation window doesn't seem to progress at all.

There is no need to wait to get the keyboard layout option more than 5 minutes, right? But I waited for about 1 hour. No progress.

So I selected shutdown and restarted without CD. I went to Windows 7 and saw that my 40 GB partition had been divided into two parts. I repeated the above process. Ubuntu detected its previous installation attempt and asked to reinstall as the first option. Again the same result.
Then I even switched to DVD-RW, again the same results.

What is the problem, and how can I fix it? Could it be the iso file itself?

For further detail:

I'm using a Corsair 4 GB DDR3 RAM. So I guess that this doesnt have any role in this problem. The 40GB drive is actually a 160 GB HDD, split into 4 40gb partitions. The partition that I used had a Windows 8 developer version installed in the past. I didnt need it, so I just right clicked and made a quick format and it got cleaned.

Then I went to the disk management in Windows 7 and right-clicked on the partion and selected delete option and then it became an unused free memory of 40 GB capacity. During Ubuntu installation, I selected the first option to install alongside Windows 7. Then it took me straight to copying files and I got stuck "in the where are you" window. After shutting down and getting back to Windows 7, in the disk management I saw that the Windows 7 was left untouched and I had two unnamed drives of basic type whose total capacity was 40 gb. This what I did. Is it ok?

General info: I am using a desktop PC. Processor: AMD Athlon x2 260 Motherboard: Asus m4a88tm HDD: 1 160 GB IDE and another 40 GB IDE. I used one of the 40 GB partitions on the 160 GB drive and not on the 40 GB HDD itself

Comment: Have you try installing using Live USB?

Comment: Is this a laptop, or are you using a USB keyboard?

Comment: Could you describe in some further detail what you did, selecting your area? Does it work if you just type in your area in the text bar?

Also, please try to burn the ISO image to a CD-R or DVD-R (_not_ RW) This works sometimes. Or, as said earlier, try to install by creating a Live USB.

Comment: Ok I will try to check the md5 hash, try a USB or a cd/DVD-r?

Comment: Exceleration-g, I don't understand about the textbar and the area you are talking about. Pls request me, if you really need screenshots. And regarding your request to delete my previous post,I don't know how to do it. I can only edit it. Just help me out.

Comment: Md5 hash verified and no issues. DVD- r failed to install. I will next try USB and report

Comment: whew, finally I installed Ubuntu 12.04.1. I previously had the 12.04 iso, but before could try the USB installation I got hold of the new 12.04.1 version. I burned it in a cd, and it installed smoothly without any problems. Thank you all of you for helping through my first linux install.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have at least 512 MB of RAM?  That could be the problem.

My suspicion would be the .iso unless you were able to check its validity with an MD5sum or whatever the magazine provided.  Or ... when you booted the LiveCD, there should have been a menu entry to check the CD itself.  If that passes, the problem was not the .iso.

You did not say HOW you deleted the 40 GB partition and your result makes it look like the install thought it was all or part of Win7 so it split that into halves and used one half for Ubuntu.  That makes me think you MAY have deleted the contents of the partition but did not delete the partition itself.  That is very easy to do since partitioning tools have you specify WHAT you want them to do but do not do it until you separately tell them to do it and they confirm you mean it.  Basically, they may look like you have deleted before they actially have completed the deed.